How to use stellar for international remittance app from EUR to Asian Corridors
We are fintech based in Europe we are currently providing money remittance services and now would like to leverage blockchain for providing enhanced money remittance service to our users? Our focus areas are EUR to INR, CNY, PHP and MYR. Can anyone provide some guidance on how to achieve it by being compliant with regulators.
